# HTTP\2 support in Chrome 45.0.2454.101 on Mac OS 10.9.5

Tags: macos, google-chrome, http2

I don't have HTTP\2 support in Chrome 45.0.2454.101 on Mac OS 10.9.5.

Screen:

[image: Screen1]

Why? Is it normal?

And the same in Firefox 40.0.3 and Safari 7.1.8.

Maybe I have some issue with Mac OS itself?

But I HAVE support for HTTP\2 on Opera on the same machine :)

Proof:

[image: Screen2]

Comment: Mac OS is have all current updates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the issue! 
It was Avast Web shield blocking HTTP/2 connections. 
After disabling Web Shield Chrome and FF started to work with HTTP/2.

Comment: Omg, I've spent 6 hours today troubleshooting this. How did you find out it's Avast ?